# What are the supported libraries for google cardboard based AR android application development?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I want to build an AR application using google cardboard. Please suggest some good libraries which provide better functionality.
I have seen people suggesting cardboard.jar library for VR apps development but not for AR.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The [Rajawali Library](https://github.com/ejeinc/RajawaliCardboardExample) is a good place to start. You can use it to display 360 panoramic images in the side-by-side view.

The [Pan Frame Library](http://www.panframe.com/) can be used to display 360 videos in the side-by-side view. (You'll have to contact them for commercial purposes though.)

These are some very useful libraries to use if you're developing for Google Cardboard and if you're looking at images/videos!

Comment: Thanks Girish.. could u plz suggest me good libraries for object tracking for AR application development?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV for image processing and object tracking. Cardboard for display.